# Finding torque on dipole from the force on it

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, torque, dipole

The force on an electric dipole $\mathbf p$ due to field $\mathbf E$ is given by $\mathbf{F=(p\cdot\nabla)E}$. We should then be able to find the well-known torque $\mathbf{\tau=p\times E}$ by using that $\mathbf{\tau=r\times F}$. But I've been banging my head against the wall for quite some time now, not being able to show that $\mathbf{r\times (p\cdot\nabla)E = p\times E}$.

Any help?

Comment: There is a torque even when the field is uniform and there is no net force.  So you can’t derive that torque in this way.

Comment: @G.Smith I’ll accept that as an answer. How could I be so stupid to use anything anywhere! I’m dumb.

Comment: Making mistakes is how one learns a subject. You can derive the torque by considering the electric force on the positive and negative charge making up a dipole. These two forces on the “ends” of the dipole are in opposite directions so they exert a torque.

Comment: I did the exercise, simplifying $q (\mathbf{(r+\Delta r)\times (E(r+\Delta r) - r\times E(r)})$ and taking the limit that $q\mathbf{\Delta r\to p}$. But then, taking the limit, along with $\mathbf{p\times E}$, I also get an additional term $\mathbf{r\times (p\cdot\nabla)E}$. I think that is what it ought to be. Since generally, one is **not** sitting on the dipole itself. Am I correct?